# How to have the article mode presentation for multibib with report mode

Tags: bibliographies, page-breaking, subdividing, report, multibib

I make a bibliography divided into two parts using `multibib` with this code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrreprt}
...
\usepackage{multibib}
...
\newcites{doc}{Documentation citees}
...
\begin{document}
...
\bibliographystyledoc{plain-fr}
\bibliographydoc{biblio}

\renewcommand\refname{%
    R\'{e}f\'{e}rences g\'{e}n\'{e}rales}
\bibliographystyle{plain-fr}
\bibliography{biblio}
\end{document}
```

Currently I get this

[image: Double]

But if I compile the document in Article mode I get this

[image: Simple]

Finally, I would like to have the rendering article mode in report mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The relevant command for **scrreprt** (as well as for **scrbook**, **report** and **book**) is `\bibname` instead of `\refname`; to avoid the page break there's a slick trick: redefine locally `\clearpage`.

```
\cleardoublepage
\begingroup\renewcommand{\clearpage}{}
\bibliographystyledoc{plain-fr}
\bibliographydoc{biblio}

\renewcommand\bibname{%
    R\'{e}f\'{e}rences g\'{e}n\'{e}rales}
\bibliographystyle{plain-fr}
\bibliography{biblio}
\endgroup
```

The `\begingroup`-`\endgroup` pair keeps the change local.